# getting modulenotfound error when I have cv2 installed

Tags: python, windows, opencv, import, pycharm

I'm relatively new to python and am wanting to try and get cv2 to work I've imported it via command prompt using
"""
pip install opencv-python
""" from what I can tell it was successful whenever I try to do it again it says that "requirement already satisfied" however when I go into pycharm and try to do anything with it I get a modulenotfound error once again I'm super new to this but eager to learn so I hope y'all wont tear me to shreds any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to install a package inside PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

It's possible that you are using a different interpreter than the one you installed the package at. If not, reloading it should resolve the issue.

If you want to change the interpreter: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: thank you so much this has fixed my problem!

Comment: the question was determined to be a duplicate of another question that already has good answers.

Comment: in that case, should I remove my answer?